# Postgres grouping query result by row

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, express

Im new to Postgres and using it now for the first time with nodejs.
I got a table with sensor readings (temperature in this case).
The Table is something like:

| sensorID | timestamp | temperature |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 8:22pm | 22C |
| 2 | 8:23pm | 21C |
| 3 | 8:25pm | 24C |
| 2 | 8:26pm | 27C |
| 2 | 8:28pm | 19C |
| 1 | 8:31pm | 28C |

**Is there a way to create a single query to get the data to nodejs formatted like this:**

```json
[
   {sensorID: 1,
   data: [
      {timestamp:8:22pm, temperature:22C},
      {timestamp:8:31pm, temperature:28C}

   ]},
   {sensorID: 2,
   data: [
      {timestamp:8:23pm, temperature:21C},
      {timestamp:8:26pm, temperature:27C},
      {timestamp:8:28pm, temperature:19C}
   ]},
   {sensorID: 3,
   data: [
      {timestamp:8:25pm, temperature:24C}

   ]}
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SO.

To build and aggregate json objects in PostgreSQL (via SQL) you can use the functions `jsonb_build_object` and `jsonb_agg`:

```
WITH j AS (
  SELECT 
    sensorid,
    jsonb_build_object(
      'data',
       jsonb_agg(
         jsonb_build_object(
           'timestamp',timestamp,
           'temperature',temperature)))
  FROM t
  GROUP BY sensorid
  ORDER BY sensorid) 
SELECT jsonb_agg(j) FROM j;
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=8c45369bf908b9024702a6fcb7e6a12f)

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about the jsonb functions